# Row count of a stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, rowcount, executenonquery

I have various stored procedures. I need a stored procedure to execute a stored procedure and then return only the row count (number of returned rows by the called procedure) and I need to receive it in c# code.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SQL Server (which is possible from the code snippets), perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
exec('exec <your stored procedure goes here>; select @@RowCount')
```

Since you are running SQL Server, I can think of one solution that is not necessarily pretty.

Create a temporary table (table variable if you have a more recent version of SQL Server).  Then execute:

```
exec(`
declare @t table (
   <columns go here>
);

insert into @t
    exec(''<your exec here>'');

select @rowcount
');
```

And now that I've said that, I would recommend `sp_executesql`.  This goes something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'exec '+@YOURQUERY + '; set @RowCount = @@RowCount';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@RowCount int output', @RowCount = RowCount output;
```

I spent most of yesterday debugging an arcane condition that arises when you call a stored procedure inside an insert.

Comment: +1 For `@@rowcount`... but he seems to indicate that he wants to somehow suppress the result set returned by the called stored procedure.

Comment: but it's returning me the rows also.
and on the messeges i see

385 rows affected

then again

1 row affected

no server management studio

Comment: is there a way to have a single column from the result returned by the stored procedure..
like

select id from exec 'stored procedure'

Comment: @KDB . . . There is not a way that I can readily think of.  But because they are *your* stored procedure, why not have an optional output parameter that has the row count?  You wouldn't have to change existing code and you can get what you want.

Comment: i'll get into that. can you tell me how i'll be able read that out with c#. thanks for your reply.

another thing is, when I execute my stored procedure with sql server management studio, there's a message there saying 555 rows are affected. can i get that message with c#?

Comment: @KDB . . . This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/c-sharp-calling-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-return-value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your **child stored procedure**  :

```
CREATE PROC PawanXX
(
 @a INT
,@b INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT TOP 2 * FROM X

SET @b = @@ROWCOUNT

RETURN @b

END
GO
```

The main **stored procedure**  where we call all other sps

```
 DECLARE @RC int
 DECLARE @a int
 DECLARE @b int

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[PawanXX] 
   @a
  ,@b OUTPUT

SELECT @RC
```

The output for the same 
ProcessName                                        Parent                                             Child

---

ShareDrafts                                        Job12                                              Job03
ShareDrafts                                        Job13                                              Job58

(2 row(s) affected)

---

2

(1 row(s) affected)