# Return row count for each stored procedure inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735025/row-count-of-a-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure/40937034#40937034/) is somewhat similar to mine. The solution just aren't enough to satisfy my problem.
I have a stored procedure sp_ImportAll, inside which i am trying to execute 5 more procs that have simple insert update statements.

```
EXEC  sp_ImportAll
(@User_Name NVARCHAR(250))
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_A @User_Name
  EXEC sp_B @User_Name
  EXEC sp_C @User_Name
  EXEC sp_D @User_Name
  EXEC sp_E @User_Name
END
```

Within each of sp_A, sp_B, sp_C, etc. there is a bunch of Insert update commands.
My need is to get the exact no. of rows affected by each sp which i'll have to write to a log in turn.
So, for example, if sp_A has affected 5 rows, I should be able to write to a log this way :

> sp_A executed for @User_Name. Affected row count : [Row Count].

Found one of the ways which I have mentioned in the linked question. Was wondering if there's a better and an elegant way to achieve this

Comment: I think one option would be to handle everything inside stored procs,i mean each one has their own logging of rowcount

Comment: I agree with @TheGameiswar. Either log it from within each SP or return the @@ROWCOUNT from the PROC into a var to write to your log table

Comment: But the @@ROWCOUNT will only capture the last Update or Insert statement in the PROC. If there are multiple in each PROC, then it won't capture the preceding ones. So handling the logging inside each PROC is a better solution.