# execute stored procedure based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

i tried to insert data in database using stored procedure but according to some condition. for example if data is already exists in database the the stored procedure should not be executed. 
i am doing the following code but it return 0 every time rather then i want. What can i do

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SaveUser
(
  @cid int,
  @firstname varchar(20),
  @lastname varchar(20),
  @dob datetime,
  @gender varchar(20),
  @add varchar(100),
  @email varchar(40),
  @quali varchar(20), 
  @yop varchar(15), 
  @exp varchar(10),
  @pass varchar(20)

)
AS

declare @result int

if  EXISTS( select Email_ID from Registration where Email_ID=@email )
begin
    set @result=4;
    return @result;
end

else
begin
    insert into Registration values(@cid, @firstname, @lastname, @dob, @gender, @add, @email, @quali, @yop, @exp, @pass );
    set @result =0;
    return @result;
 end
```

Comment: When you say @result is always 0, does the data get inserted everytime you call the SP?

Comment: "return 0 every time" - I expect you're examining the wrong output - how are you calling the stored procedure and/or obtaining the 0?

Comment: no data is not inserted it work fine but return 0 always

Comment: Please show the code that's calling this stored procedure/obtaining the 0. The code you've shown looks correct, so the problem is in the code you're not showing us. That's exceptionally difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply proceed as follows;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SaveUser
(
  @cid int,
  @firstname varchar(20),
  @lastname varchar(20),
  @dob datetime,
  @gender varchar(20),
  @add varchar(100),
  @email varchar(40),
  @quali varchar(20), 
  @yop varchar(15), 
  @exp varchar(10),
  @pass varchar(20)    
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @return int

if NOT EXISTS(select Email_ID from Registration where Email_ID=@email) 

insert into Registration values(@cid, @firstname, @lastname, 
                                @dob, @gender, @add, @email, 
                                @quali, @yop, @exp, @pass )
If (@@ERROR <> 0)
Begin
  Set @return = 4
Else
  Set @return = 0
End

Return @return

END
```

Comment: but i want to provides some error message to user eg. user already exist, registration successful etc. for that i want some return value

Comment: Use the `@@ERROR` parameter, `IF (@@ERROR <> 0) set @result =0`

Comment: will u explain it i am new for sql server

Comment: it still return 0 what i can do

Comment: If it returns zero, means the data has been inserted.

Comment: Check if you have a transaction where the stored procedure is being called. Must debug to know further :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use raiseerror event for this scenario

```
if  EXISTS( select Email_ID from Registration where Email_ID=@email )
begin
    RAISERROR(N'Email id already exist.', 10, 2,'')
end
```

Here 10 is severity level and according to severity level sql server identified as info meassage or exception. For more information

[RaiseError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

[Database Engine Severity Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SaveUser 
(
    @cid INT,
    @firstname VARCHAR(20),
    @lastname VARCHAR(20),
    @dob DATETIME,
    @gender VARCHAR(20),
    @add VARCHAR(100),
    @email VARCHAR(40),
    @quali VARCHAR(20),
    @yop VARCHAR(15),
    @exp VARCHAR(10),
    @pass VARCHAR(20)
)
AS BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM dbo.Registration 
        WHERE Email_ID = @email
    ) BEGIN

        INSERT INTO dbo.Registration
        SELECT @cid, @firstname, @lastname, @dob, @gender, @add, @email, @quali, @yop, @exp, @pass

        RETURN 0;

    END

    RETURN 4;

END
```

Comment: then how can i get this value in c#

Comment: Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/c-sharp-calling-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-return-value