# Retrieve return value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, table-valued-parameters

I have written a table-valued parameter stored procedure, It returns the Id that was inserted. If I run it from a query inside SSMS, it works and returns the value correctly.

When I call the procedure from code, it runs, and inserts the data but does not set the return parameter I have added and marked as a return parameter.

What am I doing wrong here?

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUpdateMeeting] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Meeting MeetingsTableType READONLY,
    @Area AreasTableType READONLY,
    @MeetingLocation MeetingLocationsTableType READONLY

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @MeetingId int = 0;
    DECLARE @AreaId int;
    DECLARE @MeetingLocationId int;

    SELECT TOP 1 @MeetingId=m.MeetingId FROM @Meeting AS m;
    SELECT TOP 1 @MeetingLocationId = ml.MeetingLocationId FROM @MeetingLocation AS ml;
    SELECT TOP 1 @AreaId = a.AreaId FROM  @Area AS a;

    UPDATE Areas SET 
        Hotline=areaParam.Hotline,
        Name=areaParam.Name
    FROM Areas INNER JOIN @Area AS areaParam
    ON Areas.AreaId=areaParam.AreaId;
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT=0)
        BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO Areas
                (Hotline,Name)
            SELECT areaParam.Hotline,areaParam.Name FROM @Area AS areaParam;
            SET @AreaId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END;
    UPDATE MeetingLocations SET
        Address1=ml.Address1,
        Address2=ml.Address2,
        Address3=ml.Address3,
        City=ml.City,
        [State]=ml.[State],
        Zip=ml.Zip,
        ClubName=ml.ClubName,
        ClubDescription=ml.ClubDescription,
        MapLink=ml.MapLink
    FROM MeetingLocations INNER JOIN @MeetingLocation AS ml
    ON MeetingLocations.MeetingLocationId=ml.MeetingLocationId;
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT=0)
        BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO MeetingLocations 
                (Address1,Address2,Address3,City,[State],Zip,ClubName,ClubDescription,MapLink)
            SELECT ml.Address1,ml.Address2,ml.Address3,ml.City,ml.[State],ml.Zip,ml.ClubName,ml.ClubDescription,ml.MapLink
            FROM @MeetingLocation AS ml;
            SET @MeetingLocationId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END;
    UPDATE Meetings SET 
        AreaId = @AreaId,
        MeetingLocationId=@MeetingLocationId,
        Name = meetingParam.Name
    FROM Meetings INNER JOIN @Meeting AS meetingParam
    ON Meetings.MeetingId=meetingParam.MeetingId;
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT=0)
        BEGIN;
            INSERT INTO Meetings
                (MeetingLocationId,AreaId,Name)
            SELECT @MeetingLocationId,@AreaId,meetingParam.Name FROM @Meeting AS meetingParam;
            SET @MeetingId=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END;
    RETURN @MeetingId;
END
```

C# code:

```
...create tables...
var meetingLocationParam = new SqlParameter("@MeetingLocation", meetingLocationTable);
meetingLocationParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
meetingLocationParam.TypeName = "MeetingLocationsTableType";
var meetingParam = new SqlParameter("@Meeting", meetingTable);
meetingParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
meetingParam.TypeName = "MeetingsTableType";
var areaParam = new SqlParameter("@Area", areaTable);
areaParam.TypeName = "AreasTableType";
areaParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.InsertUpdateMeeting";
    command.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[]
    {meetingParam, areaParam, meetingLocationParam, new SqlParameter()
    {
        Value=0,
        Direction=ParameterDirection.ReturnValue,
        SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,
        ParameterName="@MeetingId"
    } });
    var otherRet = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Assert.IsTrue(ret > 0);
}
```

Comment: int retunvalue = (int)command.Parameters["@MeetingId"].Value;
will this help to retrieve the value after you execute command?

Comment: it has a value of 0.  so no, unfortunately.  I must be missing something obvious because this should be straightforward.

Comment: the otherRet is typically the affected rows and not your @MeetingId.  Just check your `command.Parameters["@MeetingId"].Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output value won't get returned from `ExecuteNonQuery`. Try creating a reference to your return parameter like this:

```
var returnParameter = new SqlParameter[]
{meetingParam, areaParam, meetingLocationParam, new SqlParameter()
{
    Value=0,
    Direction=ParameterDirection.ReturnValue,
    SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,
    ParameterName="@MeetingId"
} }

command.Parameters.Add(returnParameter);
```

Then after executing,

```
var myReturnedValue = returnParameter.Value;
```

---

You could also change

```
RETURN @MeetingId;
```

to

```
SELECT @MeetingId;
```

and then use

```
var myReturnedValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns -1, but the reference to the return parameter i add has a value of 0 which is definitely not the id that was inserted or returned from my sp.

Comment: I don't see it in your code. Where are you checking the value of the parameter?

Comment: It may be easier to just select the value instead of returning it, and then use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It worked, finally.  I will update my question with the working code and mark this as accepted.  I still don't understand why i couldn't get an output parameter or a return value to work.  but oh well, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use `ExecuteScalar` to catpure the returned value, or use the `output` parameter.

A simlar question was answered in this post.
[Calling stored procedure with return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/calling-stored-procedure-with-return-value)

Comment: Thank you for the link, unfortunately, I have seen it and that did not solve my problem.The value of the return parameter is 0. Which is not what the sp is returning.    I am going to try and use the output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get a return value from a stored procedure using ADO.NET.

My example are generic methods I've used before. You can pass an SQL command using a stored procedure or text.

1. SqlAdapter

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Returns a DataSet given an Sql Command
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="cmd">The SqlCommand object</param>
   /// <returns>DataSet</returns>
   public static DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
   {
       using (SqlConnection con = DbConnect()) // DbConnect() returns SqlConnection instance
       {
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           cmd.Connection = con;
           da.Fill(ds, "my_dataset");

           return ds;
       }
   }
   ```
2. ExecuteScalar

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Returns a single value from the database given an Sql Command object
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="cmd">The Sql Command object</param>
   /// <returns>string</returns>
   public static string GetSingleFromDatabase(SqlCommand cmd)
   {
       using (SqlConnection con = DbConnect()) // DbConnect() returns SqlConnection instance
       {
           cmd.Connection = con;

           try
           {
               object returnedValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
               if (returnedValue != null)
               {
                   return returnedValue.ToString();
               }
               else
                   return "";
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               throw;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: the value returned from ExecuteScalar is null and the returnParameter's value is 0.

Comment: @MichaelBillingham then you must check and verify if your stored procedure really is returning any value using the same parameters which you've said returned null. Check it in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed you didn't declare your @MeetingId parameter in your SP definition (you did in the body but I don't think that can be used).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUpdateMeeting] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Meeting MeetingsTableType READONLY,
    @Area AreasTableType READONLY,
    @MeetingLocation MeetingLocationsTableType READONLY,
    @MeetingId <datatype> OUTPUT -- ADD THIS
AS
```

Then in your code you can grab it with this:

```
command.Parameters["@MeetingId"].Value
```