# How can I get the first value of first DataTable by returning the dataset value in a ajax response method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dataset, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to return the dataset value in the ajax method response. But I couldn't

I just returned as dataset but I'm unable to do it

**Controller Code**

```cs
public DataSet getDetailsBasedonSessionid(int sesson_id)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sGetUser]", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sesson_id", sesson_id);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    adp.Fill(ds);
                    DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0]; enter code here
                    DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables[1]; 
                }
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**View Code**

```js
function Score(){
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("myurl")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { sesson_id: '@ViewBag.Statement' },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            result.append(k);
        }
    });
}
```

I expect the output as First data of first table. But it doesn't return anything but it's running

Comment: does your sp return data properly?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested the code but it seems like your SQL Command is incomplete. I believe it should be something like `SELECT * FROM sGetUser` or whatever fields you would like. You are not selecting anything so your result is not returning anything.

Comment: CommandType is Storeprocedure right? It shouldn't be something you said

Comment: Indeed is a Storeprocedure, I've missed that, apologies. Maybe this thread about how to return get return values from store procedures will help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210055/7380348