# Read the return value of SQL Server stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to catch on -1, 0, 1 values returning from the SQL Server stored procedure in C#.

SQL Server:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _Users WHERE UserName = @UserName AND [Password] != @Password)
BEGIN
    RETURN -1
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _Users WHERE UserName != @UserName AND [Password] != @Password)
BEGIN
    RETURN 0
END

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _Users WHERE UserName = @UserName AND [Password]= @Password)
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
```

C#

Are we able to change the returning value of the code below just by making as I want to?

```
public User getUser(string name, string password)
{
    User user = null;

    using (var connection = Database.GetConnection())
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("SP_GetUser @UserName, @Password", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", name));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Password", password));

        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                user = new User();
                user.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]);
                user.userName = Convert.ToString(reader["UserName"]);
                user.password = Convert.ToString(reader["Password"]);
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    return user; // I want to return -1, 0, 1
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling stored procedure with return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/calling-stored-procedure-with-return-value)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Answer (score 6):

```
SqlParameter returnValueParam = new SqlParameter() { Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue };
command.Parameters.Add(returnValueParam);

// Read everything from your DataReader before trying to obtain the return value
// In fact after you close the connection

var returnValue = returnValueParam.Value;
```

Notes:

1. Ensure you set `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` (and remove the parameters from the `CommandText` as it can only be the SP name when using `CommandType.StoredProcedure`).
2. You should always specify the datatype and scale/precision (if relevant) when creating a `SqlParameter` as there can be unexpected side effects allowing the datatype to be set automatically. Its also best practice to fully name the parameter, including the `@`, So

```
new SqlParameter("UserName", name);
```

should really be

```
// Where the type and length match your SP
new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128) { Value = name };
```

3. Technically the return value of a stored procedure is for the "execution status" of the stored procedure. You would normally use an `OUTPUT` parameter to return user data. However in my opinion your use-case is as good as any.
4. As noted by @marc_s: you should not use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see Naming Stored Procedures)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190669(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!