# Get a value of a select from a stored procedures in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

I make a select in a stored procedure

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE isbn = @Isbn
```

I want to get this value in a webservice.

So i make this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

object returnObj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int returnValue = -1;
if (returnObj != null)
{

     int.TryParse(returnObj.ToString(), out returnValue);
}
```

But returnValue is always null.

How can I get the value from the SELECT from my stored procedure ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling stored procedure with return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/calling-stored-procedure-with-return-value)

Comment: Are you passing the @Isbn parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private int LoadUsingOpenReader(SqlDataReader dr)
{
   return (int)dr["id"];
}

SqlDataReader dr = null;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 int returnValue = -1;

 if (dr.Read())
 {
     returnValue = LoadUsingOpenReader(dr);
 }
```