# how to display or get all names of access database by ID

Tags: c#

i have like 10 contacts on my database but the ID not Arrangement from 1 to 10 it like 1 2 3 5 6 8.... and im setting a button when click the lll1 is increase like lll1++ and Take lll1 value to ID so it display contacts by click button but when it get to number 4 or 7 for example (1 2 3 5 6 8....)
the form stop and show error that Value Cannot be null is there way to skip number if not have value
also when the ID of database finish like after 10 contacts when i press button and lll1 increase to 11 and database dont have contacts 11 it show same error Value cannot be null , help me plz this important to me thanks

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
     cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database9.accdb";
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
     cn.Open();
     cmd.Connection = cn;
     cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Contacts where ID=" + lll1.Text;
     OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     string sql = "select Attachments.FileData from Contacts where ID =" + lll1.Text;
     OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);
     byte[] ImageByte = (byte[])vcom.ExecuteScalar(); //contains 20 extra bytes
     MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(ImageByte.Skip(20).ToArray()); //Read bytes starting at position 20
     Image image = Image.FromStream(MemStream); 
     pictureBox1.Image = image;
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         fl1.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("First Name"));
     }
     cn.Close
}
public int o { get; set; }
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    o++;
    lll1.Text = o.ToString();
    button6_Click(sender, e);
}
```

---

```
  `   string sql = "select Attachments.FileData from Contacts where ID =" + 
       lll1.Text;
         if (DBNull.Value.Equals("Attachments.FileData"))
                {
            MessageBox.Show("no value");
                }
         else
                {
            OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);
            byte[] ImageByte = (byte[])vcom.ExecuteScalar(); //contains 20 
            extra bytes
            MemoryStream MemStream = new 
            MemoryStream(ImageByte.Skip(20).ToArray()); //Read byte starting at position 20
            Image image = Image.FromStream(MemStream); 
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
            }`
```

Comment: If there is no record matching the Where condition the return value for ExecuteScalar is null. Try to check if the return is null before attempting to transform that return in a byte array

Comment: how to do that sorry i'm not so good on c#

Comment: I Don't know how to get to null value so i do a condition if it null then skip or increase or stop

Comment: Check against `DBNull.Value` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Dear @Rakesh is what i,m doing right i just edit the post see the second one it doesn't work

Comment: do anyone know other way ? or currect this way plz help

Comment: try ExecuteReader and check HasRows instead ExecuteScalar.
[ExecuteReader.HasRows vs ExecuteScalar() is DBNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527300/executereader-hasrows-vs-executescalar-is-dbnull)

Comment: try ExecuteReader.HasRows vs ExecuteScalar() is DBNull [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527300/executereader-hasrows-vs-executescalar-is-dbnull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527300/executereader-hasrows-vs-executescalar-is-dbnull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if ExecuteScalar returns NULL.

```
            var result = vcom.ExecuteScalar(); //contains 20 extra bytes
            if (result != null && result != DBNull.Value)
            {
                byte[] imageByte = result as byte[];

                if (imageByte.Length > 20)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memStream = new
                        MemoryStream(imageByte.Skip(20).ToArray())) //Read byte starting at position 20
                    {
                        Image image = Image.FromStream(memStream);
                        pictureBox1.Image = image;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No image");
            }
```

Looking at the rest of the code, please consider using object/control names that make sense in the context, like avoiding lll1, button5, buton6 etc.

Read about ExecuteScalar [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8)

Also consider using parameterised SQL queries, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

Finally, wrap your connection object, `cn`, in a `using` statement.

Comment: didn' t work either it showing same error `value cannot be null` on line `` ` MemoryStream MemStream1 = new MemoryStream(ImageByte1.Skip(20).ToArray());`

Comment: Is `imageByte` null? If not, how many elements are there in `imageByte`, i.e `imageByte.Length`

Comment: i have 10 contacts imagebyte show the first id 68442 and the second one 666557 but i cant see the third one because the third one number 4 in id and in number 3 it get error and crash show the error value cannot be null

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but try the updated code and tell me what you see.

Comment: it show on console.write this  `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'`

Comment: Is this with the updated code for the length check?

Comment: there is error expected on this line `MessageBox.Show($"Cannot skip 20 elements from imageByte, imagebyte is {imageByte.Length} long.");
`

Comment: Change `if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(result))` to `if (result!=null)`.

Comment: yes it worked thanks alot it show the message now without crashing

Comment: Dear @Rakesh what does this error mean  it shown when contacts id finish  `Too few parameters. Expected 1.` on this line `var result = vcom.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: how to get max ID for database to do a code that count stop if it on max ID number

Comment: Too few params - `lll1.Text` is empty.

Comment: To get maxID, use `MAX` in sql.

Comment: sorry i mean last id not max