# Database record not getting updated

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I'm hoping for someone to be able to offer me some help please? I have spent the last 4 hours trying to fix this problem but not got anywhere.  I dont actually have an error code which is making it even more difficult, it just doesnt do anything.

What I am trying to do is Read the value in Textbox2 and minus it from the GamesPlayed field in Table1 where the JobID matches TextBox1.

I dont see what I have done wrong? Many thanks.

```
 Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database1.mdb")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "UPDATE [Table1] SET GamesPlayed = GamesPlayed - " & Val(TextBox2.Text) & " WHERE JobID = TextBox1.text"
            .Parameters.Add("@p1", Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
        End With
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where off to a good start, but you need to use the parameters you add.

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database1.mdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = conn
        .CommandText = "UPDATE [Table1] SET GamesPlayed = @p1 WHERE JobID = @p2"
        .Parameters.Add("@p1", Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
        .Parameters.Add("@p2", Me.Textbox1.Text)
    End With
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I would also recommend naming your controls something useful and not the default designer names.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.CommandText = "UPDATE ...  JobID = TextBox1.text"
```

to that:

```
.CommandText = "UPDATE ... JobID = " & TextBox1.text
```

Comment: Can you say SQL injection?

Comment: He's using it on a Access database so I don't really worry and yes I can: SQL injection ;)

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested but still not working.  Yes sorry I am using Access, also the JobID field is a number.

Comment: DonA please see orginal post.

Comment: Don, please ignore I have figures it out just had to add the GamesPlayed value in again, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will not directly return a value. If you would like to get a value, try `cmd.ExecuteReader()`. Example:

```
        Dim cmd As New OleDb ("UPDATE [Table1] SETCommandGamesPlayed = GamesPlayed - " & Val(TextBox2.Text) & " WHERE JobID = TextBox1.text")
        Dim yourvalvue As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

       Do While (yourvalue.read)
         'what you want to do
       Loop
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-execute-scalar-execute-reader-and-executenonque) is a good example of what the different execute functions do.