# Difference between ExecuteScalar() and ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sqlcommand

The title may look like usual. But I have worth question.

I referred [this](http://nareshkamuni.blogspot.in/2012/05/what-is-difference-between.html) link for difference between ExecuteScalar() and ExecuteNonQuery().

But in that they mentioned as, ExecuteScalar() work only with non-action queries.

Is it true?

Many understood `ExecuteScalar()` wrongly.

Have you guys ever tried the below code?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SCI-DT-13; Initial Catalog=exercise; Integrated Security=true");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into empdetails values('" + t_empid.Text + "','" + t_empname.Text + "','" + t_empdesig.Text + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I am sure that this code will work fine and the row will be inserted into the table.

My question is, if we can perform `action queries` in `ExecuteScalar()` then why we need `ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: ExecuteScalar and ExecuteNonQuery differences given [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery

Answer (score 4):

You're right that `ExecuteScalar` will return null for action queries.

One reason to use `ExecuteNonQuery` is that it returns the number of rows affected.

I don't think you should consider that the article you linked to be an authoritative source - better to refer to what MSDN says.

Answer (score 0):

ExexuteScalar - It returns only one value.
ExecuteNonQuery- It does only the DML operations like INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE