# HasRows property in MySqlDataReader C# always return true value?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, mysql-workbench, mysqldatareader

In my code when I debug using Visual Studio C# I noticed that although there are no rows in the query :

```
select MAX(idSalesJournal) as maxId from accountingsystemdb.salesjournal"
```

the dr.HasRows property always returns TRUE. When I continue debugging I noticed that the loop will run for 1 time before exiting from the loop. Now I have a big problem because although there are no data in the dataset how the loop will run 1 time. Then I printed the value I get in a messagebox and it shows nothing (blank). How could this happen and how can I avoid this thing ? I will put an image of the same query that I have executed in the mySql workbench which executed successfully and didn't show any rows in the result. It shows 0 rows in MySql. Same query executed in C# will return Hasrows property as True. I have put my complete code in below.

```
    public void salesJournal(string addOrRemove, string lorryNo, string invoiceNo, DateTime billDate, string source, DateTime paybackDate, string itemCode, double itemcost, string desc, double qty, double discount, double amount, string debtor)
    {

        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();
        }

        int maxID = 0;

        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //---------------------- Selecting Max ID ------------------------------------------
            cmd.CommandText = "select MAX(idSalesJournal) as maxId from accountingsystemdb.salesjournal";

            try
            {
                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows && dr != null)
                {

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {                            

                        maxID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["maxId"].ToString());

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    maxID = 0;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into accountingsystemdb.salesjournal VALUES('" + maxID + 1 + "', STR_TO_DATE('" + billDate + "', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), '" + invoiceNo + "', '" + lorryNo + "', '" + source + "', '" + itemCode + "', '" + desc + "', '" + qty + "', '" + itemcost + "', '" + amount + "', '" + discount + "', '" + addOrRemove + "', STR_TO_DATE('" + paybackDate + "', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), '" + debtor + "', '" + Program.username + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

            conn.Close();

        }


    }
```

Comment: Even there will be `0`, `MAX` does return a value in my opinion. What your command returns in your database manager? As you said your `while` loops 1 time, that means you **have** a row _actually_ and it is too normal `HasRows` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the incorrect tool for the job. `DataReader` is supposed to be used to iterate over a data set and you expect only one value (or null) to be returned.

The correct method to use is `MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`

```
try
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result != null)
    {
        maxID = Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }
    else
    {
        maxID = 0;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I guess `ExecuteScalar` is used when a single value is returned. Check [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery#:~:text=ExecuteScalar%20is%20typically%20used%20when,col1%2C%20col2%20from%20sometable%20).)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ExecuteReader` use `ExecuteScalar`

Try this

```
object countObj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int maxCount = 0;
if (countObj != null)
{
    int.TryParse(countObj.ToString(), out maxCount);
}
```

Comment: How this answers to question? o.O

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is because,if nothing is there the cell value will be null in **SQL SERVER**. so the text `"NULL"` is the result returned in SQLServer.

Better use `dr.read()` to check whether the reader **HasRows**

```html
if(dr.read())  
{
 // code logic for HasRows
}
else
{
// if nothing is there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A query to a MySql database can return TWO result sets.  The first result set (aka table) is the number of rows returned/affected, the second, the results of your actual query.

So HasRows being set to true is accurate, because you're reading the first result set, which has 1 row containing the number of rows returned from your actual query.

Call dr.NextResult() to get the actual query results.