# Login form through c# forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm building a login page using C# forms for my app.
So far, I have implemented how to insert a username, with a specific username and hashed password. 
Now in order to retrieve it, i'm using this function.
Since the username value is unique, when i run my sql statement i will only receive 1 element, which is the password for this username if it is available as a string.
But when i have `string pass = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`   i get an  error in my code. Is there any way to solve this without having to create a datareader ?

```
private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        sc.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Password FROM dbo.Login WHERE username=@UN", sc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UN", tb_Username);
        string pass = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (Decrypt(pass) == tb_Password)
        {
            Find_Resource show_now = new Find_Resource();
            show_now.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        else MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentials");

        sc.Close();


    }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the cmd.executereader to

```
string pass = string.Empty;
using (var sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection | CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
{
     if(sqlDataReader.Read())
     {
         pass = sqlDataReader.GetString(0);
     }
}
```

And whenever you get an error use a try catch to capture it

so place all the code above in

```
try
{
 //tha code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

[ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx)

This way you can find the actual exception that is thrown.

Comment: Both answers worked, but this worked better in my code

Answer (score 4):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) returns number of affected rows. It supposed to be used with INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries. You should use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) - it returns first cell of first row from query results:

```
string pass = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

NOTE: Make sure you are wrapping your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` into `using` blocks. That will ensure objects are disposed even in case of exception:

```
public string GetPassword(string username)
{
     string query = "SELECT Password FROM dbo.Login WHERE username=@UN";

     using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
     {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UN", tb_Username);
          conn.Open();
          return (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     }
}
```

And your main method:

```
try
{
    if (Decrypt(GetPassword(tb_Username)) != tb_Password)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentials");
        return;
    }

    Find_Resource show_now = new Find_Resource();
    show_now.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery. You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.

Check this
[What is the difference between ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery)