# I want to chose distinct maxno with where class from SQL Server table in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

If there is no result in the table it should return zero, but currently, it is returning -1. I build my logic that if there is zero do this and if it is not zero mean record exist to do this. I am new to C# and SQL Server. Kindly let me know if there is any mistake in my code.

```
int UserExist = 0;

using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"select DISTINCT max(billno) AS bill from sale where ([date]='" + bildt.Text + "')  ", con)) {
    UserExist = (int)cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (UserExist > 0) { 
        do this
    } else {   
        do some thing   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

`ExecuteScalar` executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

`ExecuteNonQuery` executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected. For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.

```
int UserExist = 0;
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"select DISTINCT max(billno) AS bill from sale where ([date]='" + bildt.Text + "')  ", con))
{
     UserExist = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
     if (UserExist > 0)
     { 
        do this
     }
     else
     {   
       do some thing   
     }

}
```

Also some additional points.

1. Rather then using the Parameters as String, try to use Parameterized Query. For more information read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

After search on internet i found solution.

```
int UserExist = 0;
                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"select COUNT(*) from sale where ([date]=@date)  ", con))
                {   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", bildt.Text);
                    UserExist = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                   if (UserExist > 0)
                    {using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select DISTINCT max(billno) AS bill from sale where ([date]='" + bildt.Text + "')  ", con))
                        { using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {while (dr.Read())
                                {
                                    String x = dr["bill"].ToString();
                                    txttemp.Text = x;
                                    int a;
                                    int.TryParse(txttemp.Text, out a);
                                    billno.Text = (a + 1).ToString();
                                    txttemp.Text = "";
                                }
                                dr.Close(); dr.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    else {do some thing }
```

Comment: You should use a Parameter for the second `cmd` as well - especially if you need to cast a TextBox text value to a Date.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain Single value result from tsql query in C# you need to call ExecuteScalar.

You can read more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2974203/1666800)

Answer (score -2):

I am not familiar with C#, but I believe that ExecuteNonQuery() is used when you want to do  UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE

I think you need to use ExecuteReader

I hope that helps