# Select Values in From SQLServer & Show in The Labels in ASP

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to Select Values ex(Date,Time....)from SQLServer on the PageLoad & shows Them in The Many Labels. i try this code but in all labels shows the Time . i want to show All Values not one value in all labels . Please help me .

string strquery = "select Time,Date,SeatPrice,EventName from Event_SingleReservation";
        SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection();
        connection2.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = connection2;
        cmd2.CommandText = strquery;

```
    string eventname = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    lbl1_EventName.Text = eventname;



    string eventdate = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    lbl2_EventDate.Text = eventdate;

    string eventtime = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    lbl3_EventTime.Text = eventtime;

    string seatprice = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    lbl_seatpriceshow.Text = seatprice;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExecuteScalar() selects only one value from the first column - i.e. using it against `select Time,Date,SeatPrice,EventName from Event_SingleReservation` will return only *Time* which is the first column.

To select all values you should use ExecuteReader()

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    lbl1_EventName.Text = reader[0];
    lbl3_EventDate.Text = reader[1];
    ...
}
```

See [What is the difference between ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery)