# SQL Query always Returning -1 as result in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

In my code, am always getting the Value of 'user_id' as -1. is that anything Wrong in the Query???

and i am also want the join query for that.

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    var user = Page.User.Identity.Name;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserId from Users where UserName='"+user+"'", con);
                    var user_id=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Gender from UserDetails where userId='"+user_id+"'");
                    var gender = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (rdr.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }
            }
```

Comment: Try cmd.ExecuteScalar and cast it to an int or long before assigning to a var.

Comment: You should only use `ExecuteNonQuery` if you don't expect a result. In this case you probably want `ExecuteScalar` instead. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery

Comment: [Return Value
Type: System.Int32
The number of rows affected.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Check your Where clause whether the username exists within your table of Users or not and also as @JoeC mentioned, use `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: also use [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent sql injection attacks

Comment: @jeyanthi : use ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteNonquery 
and also provide info what you want to achieve

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal why? What benefit do you think they provide in *this* case? It's not protection from SQL injection, that's achieved by parameterized queries. It's not simplicity, performance or maintainability

Comment: @jeyanthi you are going good .. But use ExecuteScalar() .As single result is required to return .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Apologizes. At first look it seemed OP was trying to return a Dataset, thats why I suggested use of **Stored Procedure**. I checked OP query again and realized **Stored procedure** in not necessary in this case, what OP is trying to achieve is this `select u.UserId, ud.Gender from Users u left join UserDetails ud on u.UserId = ud.userId and u.UserName = '"+user+"'"`.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal again, why? There is no difference between a query that returns one value and one that returns many. You don't need a stored procedure for this at all. BTW your statement uses string concatenation, allowing SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Neglect **SQL Injection** stuff this part can be handled with or without use of stored procedure. The thing I tried to convey is why go for two database call using two different queries when same can be achieved in one liner. `select u.UserId, ud.Gender from Users u left join UserDetails ud on u.UserId = ud.userId and u.UserName = @Username`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return any results. If you want to return a single value, use ExecuteScalar.

Second, by concatenating strings to create a SQL statement you are vulnerable to SQL Injection and conversion errors. Google for "Bobby Tables". Or imagine what would happen if someone entered `'; DELETE FROM Users;--` as the username.

Third, if you want to retrieve a user's details, *don't* perform two separate queries. Use a JOIN, eg:

```
var query = "Select Gender from UserDetails d " +
            " inner Join Users on Users.UserId=d.UserID " + 
            " where UserName=@user";

var genderCmd=new SqlCommand(query);
genderCmd.Parameters.Add("@user",SqlDbType.NVarChar,30);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    genderCmd.Connection=con;
    genderCmd.Parameters["@user].Value=user;
    var gender=(string)genderCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return gender;
}
```

You can store the query and command in fields and reuse them as necessary, eg:

```
void InitializeCommands()
{
    var query = "Select Gender from UserDetails d " +
                " inner Join Users on Users.UserId=d.UserID " + 
                " where UserName=@user";

    _genderCmd=new SqlCommand(query);
    _genderCmd.Parameters.Add("@user",SqlDbType.NVarChar,30);

}

//....

public string GetGender(string user)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        genderCmd.Connection=con;
        genderCmd.Parameters["@user"].Value=user;
        var gender=(string)genderCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return gender;
    }
}
```

You can use the asynchronous versions of Open, ExecuteScalar to avoid blocking a thread while waiting for the server to respond, eg:

```
public Task<string> GetGender(string user)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await con.OpenAsync();

        genderCmd.Connection=con;
        genderCmd.Parameters["@user"].Value=user;
        var gender=await genderCmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        return (string)gender;
    }
}
```

IO operations like calls to the database are handled using IO completion ports at the network subsystem level, not threads.

Comment: yes, Thank you sir for your useful informations, its working. and i learned a lot from this

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNotQuery`.

**ExecuteNonQuery**:

1. It will not return any data.
2. It is used with insert and update.
3. It returns only the number of rows affected.

**ExecuteScalar**:

1. It returns only one value.
2. That value will the first column first row value.

**ExecuteReader**

1. Its for command objects.
2. It returns the value given by database through select statement.

Comment: Good Explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery` does not return anything but the number of affected records for INSERTs, DELETEs or UPDATEs. It returns -1 for all other types of queries.

What you want is `ExecuteScalar`. Please note that the result of a query can also be `NULL` (`DBNull.Value`).

Answer (score 0):

AS MSDN says, ExecuteNonQuery returns:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

In your case, you will need for sure to use `ExecuteScalar` method, that returns the first value of your query result. You should also use query parameters instead of passing them as text, as it would lead you to have SQL injection

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserId from Users where UserName= @user, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
int user_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //NOTE THAT YOU WILL ALWAYS HAVE TO CAST THE RESULT, AS IT RETURNS Object
```

Comment: Note also that you should always check the result for `null`/`DBNull.Value` before you cast.

Comment: Bobby tables. String concatenation. SQL Injection. NO. Assume people will copy the answer as is. Create a properly parameterized query, eg `"SELECT ... UserName=@user",con);cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",user);"`. It's only one more line