# Checking if MS Access database in ASP.NET C# returns any rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have this code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtLoginUserName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtLoginPassword.Text.Trim());

string sqllogin = "SELECT [username],[password] FROM users WHERE ([username] = @userName AND [password] = @password) ";

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = sqllogin;
    int store = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    Label4.Text = store.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Whenever it executes, it prints out `0` in `label4`. Is that the correct way to check how many rows are returned?

Comment: Uhm, why are you using `ExecuteNonQuery`? If you want to count the data sets that would be returned, use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` and `ExecuteQuery`. Then look at the result set for row/column 1/1 it will have the value of `COUNT(*)`. Otherwise execute the query as is (but with `ExecuteQuery` and count the number of rows returned in the C# code - depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Or best way is to create a stored procedure and get return table, then you can do whatever you want to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtLoginUserName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtLoginPassword.Text.Trim());

string sqllogin = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE ([username] = @userName AND [password] = @password) ";

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = sqllogin;
    var store = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    con.Close();
    Label4.Text = store.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: what does execute scalar does if you could please explain

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question ExecuteNonQuery() should return the number of rows affected. However that query is not doing a great deal for you there.

If you just want to know how many data rows match that un / pwd combination, then I would change it to

```
"SELECT COUNT([username]) FROM users WHERE ([username] = @userName AND [password] = @password) ";
```

I still don't see how much use that would be to you, but you know what you are trying to do :-)