# SQL query output not viewing on textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, ado.net

My output on SQL query is not viewing on my textbox, when the form load it must be automatically inserted to my textbox. The only output on my textbox is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`

I don't know whats wrong or missing on my codes. Please help me, sorry I'm just a newbie on c#

Any type of response is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
private void EmailGen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connect.Open();
    string emailto = "select emailaddress from emails where password = ''";
    string emailfr = "select emailaddress from emails where password != null";
    SqlCommand emailt = new SqlCommand(emailto, connect);
    SqlCommand emailf = new SqlCommand(emailfr, connect);
    emailt.ExecuteNonQuery();

    txBEmailRec.Text = emailt.ToString();
    txBEmailFr.Text = emailf.ToString(); ;
    connect.Close();

    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'kwemDataSet.tblProducts' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.tblProductsTableAdapter.Fill(this.kwemDataSet.tblProducts);
}
```

Comment: You should use `ExecuteScalar();` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery();` And also, you code seems to missing to execute `emailf` SqlCommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ExecuteScalar();` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery();` And also, you code seems to missing to execute `emailf SqlCommand`.

You could see this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery) as well.

```
private void EmailGen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connect.Open();
    string emailto = "select emailaddress from emails where password = ''";
    string emailfr = "select emailaddress from emails where password != null";
    SqlCommand emailt = new SqlCommand(emailto, connect);
    SqlCommand emailf = new SqlCommand(emailfr, connect);

    txBEmailRec.Text = emailt.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    txBEmailFr.Text = emailf.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    connect.Close();

    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'kwemDataSet.tblProducts' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.tblProductsTableAdapter.Fill(this.kwemDataSet.tblProducts);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much **Balagurunathan Marimuthu** it works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @vicserna1997 Glad it helped. please mark this answer as helpful and if you can up vote as well. :)

Comment: I will :) I also have another problem

Comment: @vicserna1997 Please post that as another question and Comment your new question over here. I will try to answer it.

Comment: Thank you but I have to wait 90 minutes for another question **Balagurunathan Marimuthu**

Comment: @vicserna1997 You are welcome and No problem. Paste your new question link here once you post it. So, that I can answer your question if I can. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help **Balagurunathan Marimuthu**

Comment: You can post your problem if it can able to describe it here.