# Retrieve Auto Increment ID from SQL Database after Insert Statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, auto-increment

Below here is my code to **Retrieve Auto Increment ID After Inserting data into database.**

However, I am getting Auto Increment ID before Inserting data into database.

How can I get auto increment ID after insert into database?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {           
            RetrievePRReqID();
        }
    }
```

//Retrieve ID method

```
   private void RetrievePRReqID()
     {
        try
        {
            string query = "Select IDENT_CURRENT('tblPRRequest')";
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlCon.Open();

            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                int value = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString()) ;
                txt_PRNO.Text = value.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
          }
        }
```

//Request button Method

```
     protected void btn_Request(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO tblPRRequest (RequestTo,RequestFrom,RequestedByName) " +
            "VALUES (@RequestTo,@RequestFrom,@RequestedByName)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, conn))
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, sqlCon);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestTo", lblPurchasingDept.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestFrom", ddlDept.SelectedItem.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedByName", SUserName.Text);                   
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        ***//After Insert into the table, I want to retrieve latest generated Auto Increment ID in here.***
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By referring sample answer from @Mx.Wolf, I modified a bit to get the right answer, below here is the codes that is working :

```
     protected void btn_Request(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object id ;
        string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO tblPRRequest (RequestTo,RequestFrom,RequestedByName) " +
            "output inserted.PRReqID " +
            "VALUES (@RequestTo,@RequestFrom,@RequestedByName)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, conn))
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestTo", lblPurchasingDept.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestFrom", ddlDept.SelectedItem.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedByName", SUserName.Text);

                id = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar(); //the result is of Object type, cast it safely
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(id.ToString()); // Access it like this
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in SQL Server documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> The OUTPUT clause may be useful to retrieve the value of identity or computed columns after an INSERT or UPDATE operation.

You have to change your SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO tblPRRequest (RequestTo,RequestFrom,RequestedByName)  
OUTPUT inserted.ID
-------^^^^^^^^_^^
VALUES (@RequestTo,@RequestFrom,@RequestedByName)
```

and now you can use ExecuteScalar to get the inserted value

```
 protected void btn_Request(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
    int id= 0;
    string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO tblPRRequest (RequestTo,RequestFrom,RequestedByName) " +
        "output inserted.ID" +
        "VALUES (@RequestTo,@RequestFrom,@RequestedByName)";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, conn))
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestTo", lblPurchasingDept.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestFrom", ddlDept.SelectedItem.Text);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedByName", SUserName.Text);
                            
            id = (int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar(); //the result is of Object type, cast it safely
        }
    }
    
    Debug.WriteLine(id.ToString()); // Access it like this
  }
```

Comment: Please change "...  OUTOUT inserted.ID  ..." to "... OUTPUT inserted.ID  ...".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     protected void btn_Request(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO tblPRRequest (RequestTo,RequestFrom,RequestedByName) " +
            "VALUES (@RequestTo,@RequestFrom,@RequestedByName)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, conn))
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, sqlCon);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestTo", lblPurchasingDept.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestFrom", ddlDept.SelectedItem.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedByName", SUserName.Text);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        ***//After Insert into the table, I want to retrieve latest generated Auto Increment ID in here.***
        sqlcmd.Parameters["@ID"].value; // Access it like this
      }
```

In case you can chage the `ExecuteNonQuery` to `ExecuteScalar`, then it would be even easier: [What is the difference between ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery)