# Displaying the result set of a Db view in asp.net core view

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am executing a stored procedure from my asp.net core app. The procedure executes a select statement from a db view. The db view inner joins 3 tables. When I execute the following code the result set comes as an int throwing an exception as the razor view expects List, I need to receive it as a list in order to pass it to the razor view and display the table. I would appreciate any help.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public int TimeKey { get; set; }
        public int FiscsalYear { get; set; }
        public string LocationNum { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<FactWorkOrdersViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stored Procedure Test";
}

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5"><h3>Stored Procedures results</h3></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>TimeKey</th>
                <th>Fiscal Year</th>
                <th>Location Number</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.TimeKey
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.WorkOrderAltKey
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.FiscsalYear
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.LocationNum
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Location
                </td>

            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult SPTest(ReportViewModel model)
    {
        DbConnection connection = db.Database.GetDbConnection();

            using (DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "ExecuteReport";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReportId", model.ID));

                if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

                var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                //var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
                return View(result);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks @Amogh

```
public IActionResult SPTest(ReportViewModel model)
        {
            List<ViewModel> viewModel = new List<ViewModel>();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=ServerName;database=DBName; user id=user_id; password=password; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ExecuteReport", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReportId", model.ID));

                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        foreach (var item in rdr)
                        {
                            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel
                            {
                                TimeKey = (int)rdr.GetValue(0),
                                FiscsalYear = (int)rdr.GetValue(2),
                                LocationNum = (string)rdr.GetValue(5),
                                Location = (string)rdr.GetValue(6)
                            };

                            viewModel.Add(vm);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate.
Please refer to [What is the difference between ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/what-is-the-difference-between-executescalar-executereader-and-executenonquery) for more information.

Short answer : You need ExecuteReader not ExecuteScalar.
ExecuteScalar returns first column's value of first row. ExecuteReader will return the list of rows which we can iterate through and display on your page.