# textBox3 specific key to make accounts

Tags: c#

I am coding an Application with my friend and I am having some trouble figuring out how to make the 3rd textbox contain a certain word/key to continue in order to make the account

Here is what the form looks like

[image]

Then here is the entire code for the database part of where it creates the account.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!textBox1.Text.Equals("") && !textBox2.Text.Equals("") && textBox2.Text.Equals(textBox3.Text))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                using (SHA256 hash = SHA256Managed.Create())
                {
                    Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
                    Byte[] result = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(textBox2.Text));

                    foreach (Byte b in result)
                    {
                        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
                    }
                }

                string connectionString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=majorpayne;";

                string query = "INSERT INTO staff(USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + sb.ToString() + "')";
                string query2 = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE username='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND password='" + sb.ToString() + "'";

                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
                MySqlCommand checkCommand = new MySqlCommand(query2, databaseConnection);
                MySqlDataReader reader;

                try
                {
                    databaseConnection.Open();
                    reader = insertCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Close();
                    reader = checkCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Created Account.");
                        {
                            Login main = new Login();
                            main.Show();
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Database Error (404)");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help make a way where the textBox3 equals a specific word thanks in advance.

And for a short explanation, I want the textBox3 to have a "key" in it that checks if the key is the exact key and if the correct key is there, it goes on and creates the account with the user/pass that was entered.

Comment: what C# **type** is the **key** you wanted, and give a sample value?

Comment: where you have used textbox3 in the code ?

Comment: @LeiYang so what the key is doesn't really matter it could be a word or an actual key but what I am going for is something like where I put the "key" in the textbox3 and if it is correct it continues and creates the account with the username and password, but if the key is wrong it makes a popup and says the key is invalid.

Comment: why don't you call it string, but call it key?

Comment: I'm just trying to have it look like this
Username: NotRealWolf
Password: ************
Key: AE181FDDF9B1C
And then if the key is valid then it will pop up with a box saying
"Account Created!"
Then in the database, the account is created under staff.

Comment: You need to fix the mistakes [we've pointed out previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171278/). That's [not how to hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130997/). That's [not how to construct SQL commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/). That's [not how to run a SQL INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974154/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add label Under textBox3 Then on textBox3_KeyUp Event Write your Code Like This

```
private void textBox3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "Your Key")
        {
            label1.Text = "correct key";
            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "wrong key";
            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I like that Idea but I am also trying to make it secure so it checks if that is the key and if it's not it won't make the account in the database.